# Learn how to make Flair for my users (javascript snippets)

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, iframe, code-snippets

I wanted to give my users a little piece of JavaScript or HTML code that they could put on their site and show information about them. Kind of like StackOverFlows new feature [Flair](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair).

I have an idea of how to code it. I was going to give them some JS with a HTML that had a DIV id="MySite_Info". Then the JS would go to my site and pull some JSON or XML and then fill in the data with a DIV in the HTML I gave them on their site.

**Is there a better way to do this?** Or any examples online I should follow? Whats the best way to create these javascript snippets? (Not sure what the proper name is)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two basic options.

1. Images (and pictures of text suck)
2. JavaScript - as you described

The approach I would take would be to:

1. Dynamically generate the JS using a server side process. This would include data for the user (using a JSON generator to easily produce the data in a suitable format).
2. Build the badge using standard DOM methods
3. Find the element with the document id and appendChild the generated badge

Comment: Building the badge using DOM methods is 10x to 50x slower than using innerHTML with raw HTML. I would recommend just piping back HTML from a web service into a div.

Comment: I think I will just send back HTML and use innerHTML. Thanks for the help guys.